# Docker not mapping port using gunicorn

Tags: docker, ports

I'm running gunicorn inside a docker container. I know this works because sshing into it and curling localhost:8000/things in docker container gives me the response I want, however, I am not able to reach this on my host, despite docker telling me the port has been mapped. What gives?

I ran

```
docker run -d -p 80:8000 myapp:version1.1 /bin/bash -c 'gunicorn things:app'
```

`docker ps` gives me

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
614df1f2708e        myapp:version1.1  "/bin/bash -c 'gunico"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8000/tcp   evil_stallman
```

On my host, curling locahost/things gives me

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

However, when I `docker exec -t -i 614df1f2708e /bin/bash` and then `curl localhost:8000/things`, I succesfully get my correct response.

Why isn't docker mapping my port 8000 correctly?

Comment: Are you on a mac?

Comment: yes i am on a mac, also using docker for mac :P

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Macs don't natively support docker, but rather have to run a docker machine on a VM that supports docker. So you'd need to curl from the VM's IP/hostname, not localhost.

Comment: supposedly you can curl localhost using docker for mac since it doesn't need docker-machine. I'm not totally sure. Tried to find it's IP by running `docker.local`. no dice

Comment: Does `docker run -d -p 80:80 httpd` and `curl http://127.0.0.1` work?

Comment: That does work.

Answer (score 28):

When you publish a port, Docker will forward requests into the container, but the container needs to be listening for them. The container has an IP address from the Docker network, and your app needs to be listening on that address.

[Check your gunicorn bind setting](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#bind) - if it's only listening on `127.0.0.1:8000` then it's not binding to the container's IP address, and won't get requests from outside. `0.0.0.0:8000` is safe as it will bind to all addresses.

Comment: @Eliot after mucking around for hours and lot of conflicting solutions, your solutions made my day :: "0.0.0.0:8000 is safe as it will bind to all addresses.". Thanks a lot!!

Comment: "safe" may be somewhat overstating it... binding to all addresses is not good practice. https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b104_hardcoded_bind_all_interfaces.html

Comment: @KevinD In general yes but I'm not sure this applies in the context of Docker, which is already providing some isolation.

Comment: @Alec - indeed. "Some" isolation being the operative word. Defense In Depth.... Assume Docker is secure at your peril.

Comment: Is there another approach to use when running servers inside of docker containers?