# How to access docker images in web?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm new in docker and I'm struggling with running one image which I would like to access in my localhost.
This is the order I'm using.

```
1.docker-machine start default (starting vm)
2.docker-machine env
3.(coping the @for command which has displayed and paste to my terminal)
4.docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8000:80 image_id
 it generates the long string, container I guess
5.docker container run image_id - this says that "Application startup complete."
```

After that, I want to access this in my browser using the above IP. The page cannot be displayed. What am I doing wrong ? I'm a windows user

also this is the terminal message after running the last command:

```
[2020-04-06 19:50:15 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-04-06 19:50:15 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (1)
[2020-04-06 19:50:15 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2020-04-06 19:50:15 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2020-04-06 19:50:15 +0000] [7] [INFO] Started server process [7]
[2020-04-06 19:50:15 +0000] [7] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2020-04-06 19:50:15 +0000] [7] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the application on the browser? Make sure you are using `http://localhost:8000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used `docker-machine`, look at the output from `docker-machine env` to get the IP address of the docker VM. Then connect to that IP address on the published port. Typically that would be port `8000` from your example, however you've bound to the loopback interface which is not externally accessible when you ran:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8000:80 image_id
```

So find that container (`docker container ls`), stop it (`docker container stop` on the container id or name), and start a new one with:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 image_id
```

Then connect to the docker-machine VM's IP address on port 8000 to access your app. Note that the second port number (`80`) in the above command must match the port your application inside the container is listening on. So if you've changed this port in your app based on other answers here, you'll need to change the target port above.

Comment: docker-machine env shows http://192.168.99.100:2376/. Should I put it to the docker run ?

Comment: @munih1 no, you should put 192.168.99.100:8000 in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check to see if the container is actually running by using the command: `docker ps`

**If you don't see your container listed**, it must have exited. Check the logs to troubleshoot.

**If you do see your container listed**, ensure you are going to `localhost:8000` in your web browser.

If you've made it this far, there is some other underlying issue that I cannot decipher from this post.

Comment: I can see the container listed when using docker ps

Comment: I've provided some new details

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Docker issue.

You need to bind `0.0.0.0:8000` in your gunicorn configuration.

If you are running using CMD in dockerfile, then update CMD (add -b 0.0.0.0:8000):

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then access using this:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39786876/8405123) for more detail.

Comment: unknown shorthand flag: 'b' in -b :(

Comment: I just added CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"] to docker file. docker container run image_id, still doesn't work :(